# Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following: ;

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
 2  TRIGGER c##iam_admin.AFTER_LOGON_TRG AFTER LOGON ON c##iam_admin.SCHEMA
 3  BEGIN DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module(USER, 'Initialized');
 4  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=c##iam';
 5  END c##iam_admin.AFTER_LOGON_TRG;
 6  /
 Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

when i check show errors it gives

```
Errors for TRIGGER C##IAM_ADMIN.AFTER_LOGON_TRG:
```

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the
         following:

Comment: Extected one of the following what?

Comment: Why did you add the Oracle 11 tag when you are clearly using Oracle 12?

Comment: one of the following: ";"

Comment: actually I'm  from mechanical background..dont know much abt prgamming, m jst copy pasting the commands....these were previously run on Oracle 12....but m running it on 11

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but the closing tag should be just a label and not a qualified name. Try:

```
create or replace trigger c##iam_admin.after_logon_trg
    after logon on c##iam_admin.schema
begin
    dbms_application_info.set_module(user, 'Initialized');
    execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema=c##iam';
end after_logon_trg;
```

I'm not able to test right now and I'm not sure you can even use an end tag there, so if that doesn't work, try ending with just

```
end;
```

Comment: I confirmed with a sample trigger of my own that William's answer is correct.